# Servidor de aplicação ou programa Java que determina protocolo TLS enviado?

Tags: java, segurança, servidor, tls

Tenho um programa em Java que utiliza o JDK 7, ele está deployado em um servidor de aplicação (WEBLOGIC 10.3) . Por padrão, ao fazer requisições buscando dados no formato JSON disponibilizados por um site, o programa está usando o TLS 1.0. Esse site que busco as informações só aceita TLS 1.2 e 1.3, isso está ocasionando erro de protocolo.

O WEBLOGIC está configurado com o JDK7. Já alterei no painel de controle do Java 7 para utilizar somente TLS 1.2 em vez do 1.0, mas por algum motivo ele continua tentando fazer o handshake com o TLSV1.

Uma solução que consegui é no código determinar a versão 1.2 nas minhas requisições HTTP. Mas por certo motivo não posso deixar isso no código. Em alguns lugares fala que no WEBLOGIC eu posso setar o seguinte argumento para fazer o uso do TLS 1.2:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Mesmo setando isso na inicialização do meu servidor de aplicação o programa continua tentando handshakes com o 1.0. Por isso surgiu a dúvida do título dessa pergunta, quem determina a versão do protocolo TLS de saída em uma aplicação deployada em um servidor de aplicação? Será sempre o JRE utilizado quando colocar nada especificando a versão no código, e sempre é o programa criado quando especificar o protocolo que quero? Ou posso "sobrescrever" essas duas situações no meu servidor de aplicação e determinar que quero que use por exemplo o TLS 1.2 com o argumento de inicialização (-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2)? Ou com esse argumento estou somente definindo o que estou aceitando e não requisições de saída?

Obrigado.

Comment: O protocolo efetivamente usado é negociado entre cliente e servidor no momento do handshake dentre os protocolos oferecidos por ambos os lados. Ou seja, se quer TLS 1.2 e o outro lado suporta 1.2 seu cliente deve fornecer exclusivamente essa opção, seja passando isso no código (o que você falou que não quer) ou pegando uma configuração default. Olhei por cima o problema só, mas parece que tem um outro parâmetro que pode ser passado à JVM e parece que o anterior só funciona com as operações `HttpsURLConnection()` ou `URL.openStream()`, o que não sei se é o seu caso.

Comment: Enfim, teria que estudar melhor. Vi essas informações aqui: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-change-default-ssl-protocol-my-java-client-application-will-use